# Selecting distinct records in Hadoop and using combiner

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distinct-values

"MapReduce Design Patterns" book has pattern for finding distinct records in dataset. This is the algorithm:

```
map(key, record):
    emit record, null

reduce(key, records):
    emit key
```

On page 66 it says:

> The Combiner can always be utilized in this pattern and can help if
>   there are a large number of duplicates.

map phase emits record and `NullWritable`(which does not written on the wire). What `Combiner` tries to reduce? There is no record to reduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tries to reduce the duplicates in a map output.

Let's say you have text data of words in every line:

```
John
Adam
John
John
```

There is no point in sending every `John` to the reducer if you can combine them after the map phase and only send:

```
John
Adam
```

Which is distinct for each mapper already- thus saves bandwidth if you have a fair amount of non-distinct records in your split.